# The error of inflating class fragment android kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, inflate-exception

So, firstly I answer at your question "Are you really? There are lots of answers on it.". Yes, I know, but I really try to resolve this problem like a third day: in all SOF there are no question on my error. I have 2 similar projects: in Java and in Kotlin. But this f@#^%!@ing error only in Kotlin. But XML is identity 100%.

So, error is: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment`.

My **activity_main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/top_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.weatherapp_kotlin.fragments.TopFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottom_fragment"
        android:name = "com.example.weatherapp_kotlin.fragments.BottomFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4">
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

What i tried to do:

- To change `android:name =""` in XML to `class = ""`
- To set `android:name` or `class` on a first position
- To change `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and `ConstraintLayout`
- To change class `extends` to `FragmentActivity` (now is `Fragment` and in
  Java it works fine)
- To clean project

My `LinearLayout` has an `id`, an `orientation`. Path to classes in `android:name` are true.

I try to use fragments by this class:

```
class StartActivity: Activity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}}
```

Maybe it's a hardcode, but in Java it works fine.
I think that I don't need to show `TopFragment.kt` and `BottomFragment.kt` because I tried to tell you everything that I found in SOFs themes. But if you need - I'll show. However, an error is in XML file, so probably XML is the reason.

The complete stacktrace:

```
06-14 15:24:10.161 25861-25861/com.example.weatherapp_kotlin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.weatherapp_kotlin, PID: 25861
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.weatherapp_kotlin/com.example.weatherapp_kotlin.StartActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:174)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5550)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:418)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172)
                                                                               at com.example.weatherapp_kotlin.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.kt:9)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6003)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2425)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:174) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5550) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
                                                                               at com.example.weatherapp_kotlin.fragments.TopFragment.onCreateView(TopFragment.kt:0)
                                                                               at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2069)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:875)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1050)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1152)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2142)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5347)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:418) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172) 
                                                                               at com.example.weatherapp_kotlin.StartActivity.onCreate(StartActivity.kt:9) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6003) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2425) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:174) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5550) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

TopFragment.class:

```
class TopFragment : Fragment(), SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private var outputCity: String = getString(R.string.output_city)
private var outputClouds: String = getString(R.string.output_clouds)
private var outputHumidity: String = getString(R.string.output_humidity)
private var outputPressure: String = getString(R.string.output_pressure)
private var outputWindspeed: String = getString(R.string.output_windspeed)
private var outputMmhg: String = getString(R.string.output_mmHg)
private var outputMs: String = getString(R.string.output_ms)

private var date: Date = Date()
private var dateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("E, dd.MM")

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top, container, false)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(this)
    swipeToRefresh.setColorSchemeColors(Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN)

    checkInternetConnection(activity)
}

override fun onRefresh() {
    Handler().postDelayed({
        getData(activity)
        swipeToRefresh.setRefreshing(false)
    }, 2500)
}

fun checkInternetConnection(c: Context) {
    if (InternetConnection().isNetworkAvailable(activity)) {
        getData(activity)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Internet Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

fun getData(c: Context) {
    val apiServiceWeather = RetrofitClient().getApiServiceWeather()
    val call: Call<WeatherModel> = apiServiceWeather.getMyJSON();
    call.enqueue(object: Callback<WeatherModel> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<WeatherModel>?, response: Response<WeatherModel>?) {
            val humidity: Int? = response!!.body().getMainWeather().humidity
            val pressure: Float? = response.body().getMainWeather().pressure
            val temperature: Float? = response.body().getMainWeather().temp
            val windspeed: Float? = response.body().getWind().windspeed
            val clouds: Int? = response.body().getClouds().clouds

            textViewDate.setText((dateFormat!!.format(date).toString()))
            textViewCity.setText(outputCity)
            textViewTemp.setText(((Math.rint(temperature!! - 273.15) * 10.0) / 10.0).toString()
                    + "°C")
            textViewCondition.setText(response.body().getWeather().get(0).description)
            textViewClouds.setText(outputClouds + " " + clouds.toString() + "%")
            textViewPressure.setText(outputPressure + " " + (Math.round(pressure!! / 1.3332239))
                    .toString() + " " + outputMmhg)
            textViewHumidity.setText(outputHumidity + " " + humidity.toString() + "%")
            textViewWindspeed.setText(outputWindspeed + " " + windspeed.toString() + outputMs)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<WeatherModel>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "onResponse Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: There's more info in the stack trace than just the Exception message on the first line. Look further on.

Comment: Does TopFragment class exist? Is ProGuard enabled? Are you using `android.app.Fragment` or v4 fragments?

Comment: @Miha_x64 yes, ofc, TopFragment is exist. To my shame, idk anything about ProGuard. And I use `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: @MikeM. I looking for it about second-third day. Really, all stack is inspected by me

Comment: OK, then what's the root cause? An `InflateException` is thrown whenever anything goes wrong during inflation. That by itself doesn't tell you much.

Comment: @MikeM. and how can I found out and solve the root cause if it doesn't tell me much?

Comment: What is the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: Post the complete stack trace.

Comment: @MikeM. Complete. Hope it will help you to solve it.

Comment: Yeah, see the `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException`? That's what you want to investigate. The `InflateException` isn't the actual problem.

Comment: Anyway, you can't access the `Activity` in the `Fragment`'s constructor, or outside of any method, which it looks like is what you're doing, either directly or indirectly, somehow. Looks like you're trying to get a `String` resource there.

Comment: @MikeM. Maybe TopFragment's code will help you?

Comment: If you would like us to have a look for the specific problem, then yeah, you'll need to post that.

Comment: @MikeM. Added and I hope we'll solve it

Comment: Yeah, all those `getString()` calls can't be where you have them now. The earliest you can access the `Activity` and resources is when `onAttach()` happens, but you just can move those calls to `onStart()`.

Comment: @MikeM. It doesnt helped me. I just deleted all string resourses and the same error there.

Comment: If you completely removed all of those `getString()` calls, then the stack trace should have changed.

Comment: @MikeM. Changes added

Comment: Hm I just also pointed at the getString calls, which may or may not have been solved now. Anyway, new problem is that you declared onCreateView with `savedInstanceState: Bundle` but should be `savedInstanceState: Bundle?`. State is always null the first time.

Comment: @RobCo yes, you're right. How could I miss that.. So, you are getting my vote. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment TopFragment{37d52abb} not attached to Activity
>   ...
>   at com.example.weatherapp_kotlin.fragments.TopFragment.(TopFragment.kt:24)

I expect that would be the first line of the private vars, where you call `getString()` to get a String from the resources.

These fields are initialised during object construction, but at this time the fragment is not attached to any Context. `getString()` needs a Resources objects which comes from the Context.
This crash would happen also if you just create an instance yourself (ie. call it's constructor).

The reason its wrapped an inflate exception is because these fragments are created while parsing the xml layout. It finds the instruction to create and include the fragment, it does so but fails.

### Possible solutions

1) Wrap the calls to getString in a `lazy` delegate. This will delay
    the call to when the property is first accessed, so you just have to
    make sure you only access these properties when you are sure the
    fragment is attached. For example, inside onCreateView().

```
private var outputCity by lazy { getString(R.string.output_city) }
```

2) Mark the variables with `lateinit`, and initialise when first
    attached to context. Now you have to make sure you never access the
    properties before that, or you are greeted with a
    `PropertyNotInitialisedException`.

```
private lateinit var outputCity: String

override fun onAttach(context: Activity) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    outputCity = getString(R.string.output_city)
    ...
}
```